# FCM from multiple senders but within the same app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

send multiple notifications using FCM, but within the same server side, saying that there is multiple notification types, probably with different data payloads and different notification titles, i want the the notification manager to be able to differentiate between each notification on the client side and send them to different  `Notification Channels`?

EDIT
I tried setting notification_id and it does not work.

EDIT:
I can add a Data payload and restrict the notification in one of my classes and add a switch statement which will divide according to my Notification but i need to handle the data in the background and not foreground.

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        notificationSwitch(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void notificationSwitch(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

        if (notification.getTitle().equals("TypeOne")){
            TypeOneSendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
        else{
            TypeTwosendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }

    }


 //Ofcourse we are able to switch based on the title, or different data payloads
```

EDIT:
I converted into a data payload and edited the notification title to be able to switch the above edit

Comment: Do you want N senders to 1 device?

Comment: within the same app, yes.
so if (x happens) send notification x
else if(y happens) send notification y 
and client app can receive x and y 
how can i distinguish between x and y?

Comment: I did something similar but in the other direction, 1 sender for N devices. What I did was to create a firebase function that reads from a collection, insert in that collection different messages. The function would read the message data, like sender, receiver, event, message, everything you want. In my case it reads message from 1 sender and fire FCM for all the devices subscribed to him, some code: https://github.com/Fic-Spinoff/family-care-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by implementing a switch statement on the title is merely a hack but it definetly works

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            notificationSwitch(remoteMessage);
    }
```

and in my notification switch function as i already have remoteMessage as an argument i will just implement my senders.

```
private void notificationSwitch(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

      if(notification.getTitle() != null){
        switch (notification.getTitle()) {
            case "SenderOne":
                SenderOneSendNotification(remoteMessage);
                break;
            case "SenderTwo":
                SenderTwoSendNotification(remoteMessage);
                break;
            case "SenderThree":
                SenderThreeSendNotification(remoteMessage);
                break;
            case "SenderFour":
                SenderFourSendNotificaation(remoteMessage);
                break;
            default:
                DefaultSender(remoteMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the notification_key, which identifies the device group by mapping a particular group (typically a user) to all of the group's associated registration tokens. You can create notification keys on the app server or on Android client apps.

please check this link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

Comment: I dont want to send a single notification to multiple devices...
i want to send multiple notification from different senders within the same app to a single device....
thanks for trying though.

Comment: when you defining notification_key, you can assign that key for single device and send multiple notification just to that single device which has that key

Comment: yes but you are still restricting to one app, i want to define multiple senders to same app if i assign a notification key only the notifications with key will be called from the same app...

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the title: `FCM from multiple senders but within the same app`

If `sender == Firebase Project` then I don't think it is possible.

If `sender == a client inside the same Firebase Project` (like an iOS app, multiple servers, another Android app), then you need to create those apps inside your Firebase Project (for iOS and Android apps) and use the server key (for the servers)

If `sender == function` (like "Update Entity A", "show notification for promotion", etc), then you can use the `data` field inside the notification. We usually add an `action` field inside the `data` field. Both the `receiver` (iOS or Android app) and the `sender` (usually a server, but can also be a mobile app) know the list of possible `action`s. `Receiver`s know what to do when they receive them (if app receives "Update Entity A", then it starts the EntityAUpdateService).